# Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CAINFO

Tags: php, curl, wamp

I try to use `TwitterOAuth` which requires `cURL`. First of all, I think it is important to point that I use Win 8 64 bits with WampServer 3.0 and PHP 5.6.15 When I run the scripts (given by TwitterOAuth) I have these errors:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CAINFO - assumed 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 353
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 354
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_HEADER - assumed 'CURLOPT_HEADER' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 355
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER - assumed 'CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 356
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - assumed 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 357
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST - assumed 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 358
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER - assumed 'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 359
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_TIMEOUT - assumed 'CURLOPT_TIMEOUT' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 360
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_URL - assumed 'CURLOPT_URL' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 361
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_USERAGENT - assumed 'CURLOPT_USERAGENT' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 362
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_ENCODING - assumed 'CURLOPT_ENCODING' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 363
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_POST - assumed 'CURLOPT_POST' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 378
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS - assumed 'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS' in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 379
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Abraham\TwitterOAuth\curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\TWEET\twitteroauth\src\TwitterOAuth.php on line 394
```

So I googled my errors and found that I have to change `php_curl.dll` on this site: http://www.anindya.com/php-5-4-3-and-php-5-3-13-x64-64-bit-for-windows/ . However the dll proposed are for PHP 5.3 and 5.4, and i use PHP 5.6.15. I didn't find the actual dll used for this version of PHP.

Furthermore, my php.ini in …/bin/apache/apache2.4.17 AND in …/bin/php/php5.6.15 extension=php_curl.dllis uncommented, and if i Ctrl-F "curl" on phpinfo, the only line found is in the author table.

**Is it possible to use cURL with PHP 5.6.15 or do I need to downgrade my PHP version?**

*I have asked this question on StackOverflow and I've been redirected on SuperUser*

Comment: This looks like something that may help https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-to-use-the-ssl-certificate/12454/2